# Group with non-subnormal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

A subgroup $H \leq G$ is said to be subnormal if there exists a series:

$H \triangleleft H_1 \triangleleft ...\triangleleft H_n \triangleleft G$.

Can you all give me some examples of groups with subgroups that are not subnormal? Thanks!

Comment: Try in a non-abelian group of order $pq$, $p,q$ primes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G=S_n$ for $n\ge 5$ and $H$ be any subgroup of $G$ that is neither $1$, nor $A_n$, nor $G$.